# SUM(CASE WHEN) with condition of another aggregate function

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm fairly new to SQL and can't seem to get my query doing what I want it to do.

I want the sum of one column based on the occurrence of another condition.

My table looks something like this:

| ID | Location | Scan_Code | Scan_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PlaceA | 01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | PlaceA | 02 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | PlaceA | 01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2 | PlaceA | 02 | 2021-02-02 |
| 3 | PlaceB | 01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 3 | PlaceB | 02 | 2021-02-01 |
| 3 | PlaceB | 01 | 2021-02-02 |
| 3 | PlaceB | 02 | 2021-02-02 |
| 4 | PlaceB | 02 | 2021-02-02 |

The result should sum the occurrence of Scan 01 on any given Date per Location and sum of Scan 02 IF there was a Scan 01 on the same day for that ID.

Expected result for the table above

```
|Scan_Date |Location|Sum_Scan01|ConditionalSum02|
|----------|--------|----------|----------------|
|2021-02-01|PlaceA  |2         |1               |
|2021-02-01|PlaceB  |1         |1               |
|2021-02-02|PlaceB  |1         |1               |
```

My query currently looks like this and sums all of scan 02 regardless of occurrence of scan 01 and I can't figure out how I can include that condition as I cant just repeat the first one in the second case:

```
select

scan_date,
Location,
SUM(case when scan_code EQ '01' then 1 else 0 end) as Scan01,
SUM(case when scan_code EQ '02' then 1 else 0 end) as Scan02


from ScanDB

where scan_date between '?From' and '?To'
group by scan_date,Location
```

Thanks a lot from a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need nested aggregation, this should work:

```
with cte as 
 ( select
      id, -- include id in inital calculation
      scan_date,
      Location,
      SUM(case when scan_code = '01' then 1 else 0 end) as cntScan01,
      SUM(case when scan_code = '02' then 1 else 0 end) as cntScan02
   from ScanDB
   where scan_date between '?From' and '?To'
   group by id,scan_date,Location
 )
select 
   scan_date,
   Location,
   SUM(cntScan01) as Scan01,
   -- check if 01 exists for same id
   SUM(case when cntScan01 > 0 then cntScan02 else 0 end) as Scan02
from cte
group by scan_date,Location
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just tried it out and it gives me a syntax error 'expected something between the word 'Scan02' and the 'from' keyword'

Comment: My Select has valid syntax, you might have messed it up when applying it to your real query, e.g. missing `)`

Comment: yeah thanks...sometimes it helps to let it sit a few hours and then the additional ( just stares you right in the eye...thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use window functions:

```
select scan_date, Location,
       sum(case when scan_code EQ '01' then 1 else 0 end) as Scan01,
       sum(case when num_id_01 > 0 and scan_code EQ '02' then 1 else 0 end) as Scan02
from (select s.*,
             sum(case when scan_code EQ '01' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, scan_date) as num_id_01
      from ScanDB s
      where s.scan_date between '?From' and '?To'
     ) s
group by scan_date, Location;
```

Comment: First, thanks for the support. Second, one question: in the case when before "as Scan01" would it not have to be scan_code EQ '01'?